# Symfony 3, запись JSON данных в БД

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос.

Есть Js интерфейс, который высылает в виде json данные, их много, они имеют вложенную структуру. Мне необходимо их записывать в БД. Сейчас это реализовано костыльным способом, т.е.
Есть в одном из контроллеров action в котором:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); 
$order->setType($data['type']);
$order->setFile($data['svg']);
$order->setLogo($data['Emblem']['name']);
```

Таких сеттеров сейчас примерно 15-20 и потом сохраняем данные

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($orderItem);
$em->flush();
```

Мне это не нравится, так как подход не очень. Подскажите пожалуйста. может тут можно как-то по другому сделать, например как-то формы задействовать?

Так же особенность в том что в js-клиенте могут добавится параметры данных и их названия не соответствуют полям в Entity классе.

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать сериализатор. Например, [JMS Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставь для поля тип данных - json_array или json(в зависимости от версии doctrine).

Ccылка на доку: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#json-array